# Why did ethereum switch to using timestamps for forks after the merge?

Tags: hardforks, the-merge

The only explanation I have found is that using a timestamp allowed the execution layer and consensus layer to be updated synchronously. But using a block/slot number would also allow for that, so I don't understand why the swtich was made to using timestamps?